# How to bring zoom above overlay?

Tags: javascript, jquery, zooming, overlay

How to bring ZOOM over overlay (i.e. when you onmouseover on picture: http://testowa.testynarkotykowe.pl/testy-narkotykowe/testy-na-mocz)?

Comment: Can you add more detail to you question and describe exactly what you mean? At the moment it appears to meet your description of what it should be doing. Also, please add the relevant code to the question itself.

Comment: When you do onmouseover on one of the items and then from it: go to picture --- the zoom that is appearing is hid behind the overlay. I want to pull it to the front.

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/526tgxlrh/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a plugin called "elevateZoom" to make this zoom effect:

http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/image-zoom

you have to open your **elevatezoom.js** file and find this line:

```
self.zoomWindowContainer =$('<div/>').addClass('zoomWindowContainer').css("width",self.options.zoomWindowWidth);
```

and Replace with this:

```
self.zoomWindowContainer = $('<div/>').addClass('zoomWindowContainer').css({
    "width": self.options.zoomWindowWidth,
    "z-index": 100
});
```

It will bring the zoom to the front of that `.overlay` we created.